# Crop an image instead of stretching it

Tags: image, css

When I insert an image in a container with fixed width and height, the image stretches to fit that space. Is there a way to display the image at its normal size, but with the excess clipped out?

Answer (score 55):

The modern way is to use `object-fit: none;` (or the more common `object-fit: cover;` if you want to scale, but without stretching).

```
img {
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

97% of browser sessions support this as of 2022 May. — [Can I use?](http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit)

---

If you want to anchor the image to the top left corner instead of the center, add:

```
img {
    object-position: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm finding this centers the image, rather than anchoring it in the top-left. Any suggestions to correct that?

Comment: You can put object-position: 0 0;

Answer (score 10):

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-image: url(your image); background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
```

Then in the above DIV you can play with CSS

- width/height
- background-position

to create different crop effects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the CSS `clip` property:

```
#image_element
{
position:absolute;
clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

The downside of using `clip` is that the element has to be absolutely positioned, and is only available with the 'rect' shape.

See:

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp
- http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/clip_gallery

Answer (score 1):

Use this :
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-position.asp

background-position: 5px 5px;

and then set the height and width of the div

height: 55px;

width: 55px;

Answer (score -1):

Show it as a background image